# uu-parsinglib parsing with conditional fail

Tags: parsing, haskell, applicative

**EDITED for more complete problem:**

I'd like to create a parser (I'm using uu-parsinglib) that takes the result of a previous parser, and conditionally fails if the result contains a certain constructor:

I now realise this must be a monadic parser.

I have a grammar which contains non-direct left recursive. Below illustrates the problem, the reality is slightly more convoluted:

```
data Field = 
       Field_A  A
       Field_B  B
       Field_C  C
       Field_D  String

data A =
       A Prefix String

data B =
       B Prefix String

data C =
       C Prefix String

data Prefix = 
       Prefix Field
```

Most of the time I'm only interested in Field, and in the interests of minimising backtracking, its best to focus on that case.

I've defined an operator to help

```
(<..>) :: IsParser p => p (a -> b) -> p (b -> c) -> p (a -> c)
g <..> f = (.) <$> f <*> g
```

And I approach the problem as:

```
pField :: Parser Field 
pField =  
   ( Field_D <$> pString ) <??>
   pChainl' ( pReturn (helper) <*> pPrefix' ) ( pA' <<|> pB' <<|> pC' )
   where pChainl' :: IsParser p =>  p (f -> (pre -> f) -> f) -> 
                                       p (pre -> f) -> 
                                       p (f -> f)
         pChainl' op x = must_be_non_empties "pChainl'" op x (
                            flip f <$> pList1 (flip <$> op <*> x)
                         )
         f x [] = x
         f x (func:rest) = f (func x) rest
         helper :: (Field -> Prefix) -> 
                      Field -> 
                      (Prefix -> Field) -> 
                      Field
         helper p i n = n $ p i
```

Note I've defined a variant of pChainl that allows the initial field to be passed in, whilst keeping left association.

```
pA' :: Parser (Prefix -> Field)
pA' = ( (flip A) <$> pString ) <..> pReturn Field_A

pB' :: Parser (Prefix -> Field)
pB' = ( (flip B) <$> pString ) <..> pReturn Field_B

pC' :: Parser (Prefix -> Field)
pC' = ( (flip C) <$> pString ) <..> pReturn Field_C

-- This consumes no input
pPrefix' :: Parser (Field -> Prefix)
pPrefix' = pReturn Prefix
```

**The question**
I'd like to define

```
pA :: Parser A
```

in terms of pField, with a post filter to fail if the rightmost Field constructor is not Field_A. As has rightly been pointed out, this is a monadic parse. I can't find any compelling examples of using uu-parsinglib as a monadic parser, so what would your suggested approach be?

If I'm barking up the wrong tree, please let me know also.

Comment: The "action" of one parser can't depend on the "result" of another one, with just the `Applicative` API. That (i.e. context-sensitivity) is exactly the power that `Monad` gives you over `Applicative`.

Comment: Good point. I'm clearly going to have to have a think about things now.

Comment: Note that `uu-parsinglib` does allow you to use a monadic interface if you really, really need it. But the situation you describe sounds like you don't really need it ...

Comment: Actually, I think I do really really need it. I'll edit the question with a more compelling use case

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems like you could make a generalized conditional parser that only succeeds if the value returned by the parser passes some test. This uses the monad capabilities of course. I am not sure if this is a good thing to do with uu-parsinglib however. It seems to work fine in my testing, with one exception: when the conditional fails and no other parsers are available to consume input, the library throws an exception. (something along the lines of no correcting steps given...)

```
pConditional :: Parser a -> (a -> Bool) -> Parser a
pConditional p test = p >>= (\result -> case (test result) of
    True -> pure result
    False -> empty)
```

I would also like to know of other pitfalls that would arise from liberal use of such a conditional parser. (if any.)

Answer (score 0):

I think I've found a solution. I'm still interested in hearing thoughts on the best way to parse such indirect left recursion.

The proposed solution is

```
pA :: Parser A
pA = do
   a <- pField
   case a of 
      (Field_A r) -> return r
      otherwise   -> pFail
```